# Using PlusClient for offline access with one confirmation

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth

I am trying to implement Offline access to Google Calendar. 
I implemented Google+ Sign-in for Android with PlusClient:

```
mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this.getActivity(), this, this)
                .setActions(getActions())//, "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity")
                .setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE + " " + SCOPE_CALENDAR)
                .build();
```

and then requesting a token using:

```
token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                            LoginFragment.this.getActivity(),
                            mPlusClient.getAccountName(),
                            "oauth2:server:client_id:"+clientId + ":api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login "+SCOPE_CALENDAR);
```

Everything works as it should, except when the application is not yet confirmed with Google (first sign-in), user needs to confirm the application two times. First for the PlusClient scopes, and the second time for the offline access permission.

Is it possible to make PlusClient ask for the offline permission as well (included on the list with other permissions), so the getToken call will not ask again.

Comment: Still unsolved. Not urgent problem, but would be nicer for the user, if the app asks only once.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this blog post:  http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/03/common-problems-with-google-sign-in-on.html

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? Facing the same problem.

Comment: Not really. I haven't worked on that for a while. Everything works, but I think 2-fold confirmation is still needed.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem Luka. I'll let you know if I find a solution.

Comment: There is a much easier solution now with the new Google Plus API, so this question is somehow irrelevant now: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth